# Dangers for working temp job for only short period

Tags: resume, job-offer, job-change, background-check

I have a full-time job as a software developer that is enough to support me, but I am looking to find a temp job to help pay off student loans quicker, among some other expenses. I interviewed with a company that I found (on Craigslist) that would have me doing some simple work that I feel I could easily accomplish, for a few extra hours each week. However, I wasn't sure how I felt about the development process or technologies they use, and didn't have too good of a feeling for one of the interviewers, although I may not interact with this person much. The job is remote and I could work at a decent rate after my primary job.

My question is: if I find that this temp job is not a good fit for my time, are there any repercussions that might come from trying the job for a couple of weeks or months, and then leaving? I won't need to put this job on my resume, and I will still be working my primary job so there will be no employment history gaps, but will something like this show in a background check for future jobs, and be a bad mark against me? I'd like to have this as a casual part-time job that I can leave at anytime, even within a few weeks, just to provide myself with a bit of extra money to help reduce my loans. But I don't want to risk hurting any future opportunities in my career.

So is it alright to accept a part-time job with the intent that I can leave right away at any time if I want to? Or is that a poor attitude to have going into a job, that may impact my future career in a background check or otherwise? Thanks for any help, it would be great to have advice before I decide to take the position.

Comment: Check if your current employer allows working on the side like this.

Comment: How would this second job show up in a background check if you never mention it? Unless you're considering making it your primary job of course.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to worry... Craigslist programming jobs are short and generally not secured. Well funded employers don't use it.

You are more likely to quit because you don't get the money for your services (Craigslist is a well known place for seeking cheap/free programmers). It's a temp job, you shouldn't feel shame for quitting early.